# Input type="file" server side access

Tags: asp.net

I have the following client side code:

```
<form action="PhotoStore.aspx" id="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div>
    <input type="file" id="file"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
</form>
```

With this client side code, how will I access the uploaded file in Photostore.aspx? Request.Files is having a count = 0 :( .? Whats going wrong?

Comment: where is `runat=server` element?

Comment: There is no need for a server control.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put a name on the input field, or it won't be included in the form data:

```
<input type="file" name="file"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
Page.Request.Form["file"]
```

Comment: y runat = server? i need a pure html file independent of server controls